# How can you tell if any given preference structure is continuous or not?

Tags: consumer-theory, utility

From a given preference structure (not the utility function), how can one tell if it satisfies the continuity axiom of preferences?

Comment: Can you elicit preferences on infinitely many pairs of bundles of your choosing? That is, for any two bundles A and B, can you always elicit which one the household prefers?

Answer (score 1):

By trying to prove whether the following holds.

[image]

Note: Image taken from http://www.econ.ucla.edu/iobara/lecturepreferenceandutility201a.pdf

Comment: note: I was being sarcastic.